# Удаление элемента списка

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно удалить элемент списка, зная лишь его значение. Например,

```
List <string> names = new List<string>();
names[0]="Ivan";
names[1]="Dima";
```

Из этого списка нужно удалить элемент с именем Dima, не обращаясь по номеру в этом списке, зная только его имя

Comment: Уточните - если в списке несколько элементов с именем "Dima" - нужно удалить все?

Comment: @Zufir похожих элементов не будет

Comment: Если похожих элементов не будет - рекомендую использовать [HashSet<string>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). Работать будет быстрее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если речь идет о строках или типах-значениях, то подойдет [метод Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<string> names = new List<string>(2);
names.Add("Ivan");
names.Add("Dima");

names.Remove("Dima");
```

Для применения его с классами, класс должен реализовать [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx), для сравнения. В противном случае сравнение будет происходить с использованием [Object.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx), что для ссылочных типов равносильно сравнению ссылок.

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить новый список, в котором нет элементов со значением "Dima":

```
names=names.Where(x=>x!="Dima").ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
names.Remove("Дима")
```

Comment: Только `RemoveAll` - Дмитриев может быть несколько ;)

Comment: @Zufir, либо надо удалить _только одного_ и тогда `RemoveAll` очевидно не подходит

Comment: Да, нужно уточнить.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = (names.FirstOrDefault(o => o == "name"));
if (obj != null)
{
    int index = names.IndexOf(obj);
    names.RemoveAt(index);
}
```